# Bottom navigation doesn't navigate when item is clicked

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation menu with 3 items: Home, Favorites, and Settings. I'm using Fragment container:

```xml
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container" />
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

In the BaseFragment, where I want to actually navigate I'm using `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` where I override the `onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem)` function

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, BeerListFragment())
            .commit()
        val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        bottomNavigationView?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(object :
            BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                var activeFragment: Fragment = BeerListFragment()
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.nav_home -> let {
                        activeFragment = BeerListFragment()
                        return true
                    }
    // similiar for the other two options
                }
                childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, activeFragment).commit()
                return true
            }
        })
```

The problem seems to be that the ids of the layouts for the fragments are not checked in `when()` statement. If I pass different from `BeerListFragment()` in the first line of the `onCreate()` function, it works, so I think there should be an issue with the `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Is there any other way that I can navigate to the particular fragment? I've tried using actions in the navigation_graph, but I don't think it's necessary because I have a bottom navigation menu.

Comment: In Android Studio go to File->New->New Project, then select "Botton Navigation Activity" and look how has it been implemented by google team. Look at the files in res/menu/bottom_nav_menu.xml, check how the MainActivity has been built and look at the fragments (you don't have to use MVVM pattern).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using navigation component why do you use `childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, BeerListFragment()).commit()` ?

If you use navigation component and you want your `BottomNavigationView` item to redirect to your `fragment` you don't need any code except giving the right ids in the item of your `BottomNavigationView` menu.

Here is a quick [tutorial](https://medium.com/@freedom.chuks7/how-to-use-jet-pack-components-bottomnavigationview-with-navigation-ui-19fb120e3fb9) to help you.

Comment: Thank you, Biscuit! Your link was part of the solution :) I create a new navigation graph with the fragments I need for the bottom navigation. Thanks again :)